# Photoshop - is there a programming language?

Tags: image-processing, photoshop

I was surprised to discover that StackOverflow has a "Photoshop" tag because I need to combine Photoshop (- Pro, Creative Cloud subscription) and programming (I'm an experienced Java, C#, C++ sw engineer) for an art project.

I want to take a folder with up to 2000 JPEG files and, starting with the first file, isolate the red channel of the first file, the green channel of the second file, and the blue channel of the third file and combine those into one new JPEG file, and save it.   Then repeat this for the next 3 files, the next three, etc.

I originally planned to find a JPEG library for C# and do it all there, but if I can harness Photoshop, which I use routinely for other stuff, that might be easier.   Does Photoshop have a robust scripting/programming language with a syntax similar enough to a conventional programming language (conditional loops, file i-o, user-defined variables, functions or subroutines, etc) to do this?

Comment: You can use JavaScript with Photoshop https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf  but I would do the above with **ImageMagick**. How do you know which is the *"first"* file and the *"second"*.

Comment: The files are generated by a camera taking 1 shot every _n_ milliseconds (where _n_ is like, 600 or 1000) so their filenames are made of a timedatestamp, so I could use the filename, or the real creation time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript, VBScript (on Windows) and Applescript (on Mac) to script Photoshop - [Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).

However, for this simple task, I would use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is readily available for free on OS X and Windows.

So, if you start with these three images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could type the following into the shell/Terminal/Command Prompt:

```
convert 1.png -separate -delete 1,2    \
     \( 2.png -separate -delete 0,2 \) \
     \( 3.png -separate -delete 0,1 \) -combine result.png
```

to get this:

[image]

That command takes the first image, splits it into RGB channels (internally numbered as R=0, G=1, B=2) and deletes G and B. Then it loads the second image, splits it into RGB channels and deletes the R and B and the third image and deletes all but the blue. Then it combines the remaining 3 channels into a single output image.

It will work just the same for JPEG input/output images if you change the extensions.

Comment: So then does ImageMagick have an API?    In your example it looks like it only takes command-line arguments.      I think to do what I want where I can point the program at a folder full of files, read the filenames, sort in the correct order, count them, and iterate over them, would be easier to do in a real programming language.   Even more so if I want to add additional features like letting the user choose what order to put the channels in, confine the operation to a region-of-interest, or to give it a user-friendly UI to browse to input and output folders.

Comment: Obviously I don't know your setup - how often you need to do this, how much flexibility you need, or which OS you use. On OSX or Linux, the things you say would be quite easy in `bash` but if you are on Windows maybe a bit harder. There are C/C++, C#, dotNet, Perl, Java, PHP bindings for ImageMagick if you want them - https://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php